# What does GNU tar "--restrict" option actually restrict?

Tags: tar, gnu, coreutils

The manual of GNU tar only states that `--restrict`:

> ```
>    --restrict
>           disable use of some potentially harmful options
> ```

Can anyone elaborate on what are these "harmful" options? I could not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only option `--restrict` currently disable is the ability to spawn a subshell with the `!` command when you are prompted to replace a tape in a multi-volume archive.

```
2005/12/06 New function. Disable '!' command if given --restrict option.
```

Reference: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=tar.git;a=commit;h=ffc4fb7bdd03d095c46233770eb1a40fcaa3999c